# MVC how to correctly display localized enum in display form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, enums

I have a question regarding enums, basically I've created a localized enum drop down list to correctly disply the enums with localization.

But when i would like to show the selected enum later somewhere on another page, I don't get the localization anymore.

Any idea, or maybe anyone could give me a link to some html extension for displaying enums.

I have the following:

```
public enum Gender
{
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Base), Name = "Male")]
        M= 0,
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Base), Name = "Female")]
        F= 1,
}
```

in my view i have following:

```
@Html.LabelForModel(Model.Gender.ToString())
```

And in the controler i set:

```
Model.Gender = Gender.M
```

Instead of showing the Male from the base, i get "M" displayed.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm still, looking for an answer, if anyone can ...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue myself, I've created a custom html helper to display correctly the "display' annotation.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayEnum(this HtmlHelper helper, Enum e)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        var display = e.GetType()
                   .GetMember(e.ToString()).First()
                   .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                   .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
                   .LastOrDefault();

        if (display != null)
        {
            result = display.GetName();
        }

        return helper.Label(result);
    }
```

Comment: you get name, but i dont think you get resource for that name, did you?

Comment: @deadManN read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.getname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code in your view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender)
```

Because `Display` attribute using by `LabelFor` method to display your value.`ToString` is just converting your enum value to a string.It doesn't have any information about your attributes.

Comment: Now instead of M, I get Gender, but I need to see "Male" or localized version of it